# Image Upload on Safari: .heif file not triggering 'change' event

Tags: javascript, html, ios, image, file-upload

I'm currently building a simple image upload for a website, but I encountered a problem where it seems that the `change` event after selecting the files does not get triggered **after** files selection if one .heif file is present.

AFAIK with `accept="image/*"`the image should be converted to a `jpg`, but just nothing happens.

I used it for testing the IOS Simulator Images, which includes one .heif image in its default gallery.

Minimal example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File Upload Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>File Upload Test</h1>
<input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple accept="image/*">
<script>
  function onUploadFunction() {
    alert('File(s) selected.');
  }

  const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
  fileInput.addEventListener('change', onUploadFunction);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? Maybe it's iOS14 thing?